# Show specific attachment using json api for Wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress

When I go to:
    example.com/api/get_tag_posts/?dev=2&slug=ME3022&include=attachments

I see:

```
{
  status: "ok",
  count: 1,
  pages: 1,
  tag: {
  id: 17,
  slug: "me3022",
  title: "ME3022",
  description: "",
  post_count: 1
},
posts: [
 {
  id: 181,
  attachments: [
{
id: 397,
url: "http://example.com/files/2012/10/WebInstruction_TCH.pdf",
slug: "webinstruction_tch-3",
title: "Traditional Chinese",
description: "",
caption: "Traditional Chinese",
parent: 181,
mime_type: "application/pdf"
  },
{
id: 398,
url: "http://example.com/files/2012/10/WebInstruction_SCH.pdf",
slug: "webinstruction_sch-3",
title: "Simplified Chinese",
description: "",
caption: "Simplified Chinese",
parent: 181,
mime_type: "application/pdf"
},
```

What I want to show is a specific attachment instead of all of the attachments.  How can I do that?

Comment: Is this a plugin you are using?  If so, which plugin and do they offer some sort of documentation?

Comment: yes.  It's the JSON API Plugin found at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/
Documentation is at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

Answer (score 0):

To get the a specific attachment `&include=attachments,id=51`